# Правильно ли построен SQL-запрос?

Tags: pdo, php, mysql

Запрос:

```
select * from
(select count(`id`) from `users` where `login` = :l) as one,
(select count(`id`) from `users` where `email` = :e) as two
```

Должен возвращать количество совпадений. Но почему-то этого не происходит.

Comment: @rnddev, вероятнее всего далее в коде вызывается что-то типа `$check['one']`, в то время как желаемый массив получается так:

    $data = $check->fetch();

Comment: @Etki это то да, я заметил, а запрос не работает почему то так как нужно

Comment: @rnddev, добавьте псевдонимы для `count(id)`, иначе mysql их склеивать будет в одно поле и как попало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@rnddev](/users/23259/rnddev)](/users/23259/rnddev), если вам нужно проверять наличие юзера, то нужно использовать конструкции типа

```
SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `login` = :login OR `email` = :email
```

Что до вышеприведенного запроса, так one и two там - это алиасы не полей, а таблиц, потому что селекты перечисляются во `FROM`, и значения возвращаются в `` COUNT(`id`) `` и элементах с числовым индексом (если не используется `PDO::FETCH_*`). Чтобы one и two стали алиасами колонок, нужен такой запрос:

```
select * from
(select count(`id`) AS one from `users` where `login` = :l) as login_matches,
(select count(`id`) AS two from `users` where `email` = :e) as email_matches
```

Comment: @Etki, ясно, спасибо, помогло. `OR` использовать не могу, так как нужно показывать, что занято, логин или мэйл.

Comment: @rnddev думал, что получится коротко, но вышла простыня

    SELECT 'login' AS occupied FROM `users` WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `login` = :subject)
    UNION
    SELECT 'email' FROM `users` WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `email` = :subject)
    UNION
    SELECT 'nothing'
    LIMIT 1